# QTcpSocket reconnect to server without blocking GUI

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I have a client server application which works like a charm when server starts before client, but since i don't know if server starts first, i need client to keep trying to connect to server without blocking interface.
The best thing that came to my mind so far is making a loop like this

```
void client::initConnection(){
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readMessage()));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(clientConnected()));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnectedFromHost()));

    while (tcpSocket->state() != QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState) {
    tcpSocket->abort();
    tcpSocket->connectToHost(address, port, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    tcpSocket->waitForConnected(1000);
    }
}
```

but if i call this code in main thread it blocks gui(for obvious reasons), i thought that i might have to use threads, but it seems that not really possible to work with socket from thread different than the one it was created in.
So maybe there is a way run this method without blocking gui and changing the architecture of my app?

Comment: I don't understand why you call `waitForConnected` if you are going to handle the [`connected` signal](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#connected) anyway?

Comment: the thing is if i delete waitForConnected socket state will be ConnectingState and not ConnectedState(although i could probably change the while loop)
Addition: probably bad explanation, if i remove waitForConnected() it becomes and infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [QObject::startTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#startTimer) and [QObject::timerEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#timerEvent) methods of your `client` class (it looks like it inherited from `QObject`) like that:

```
void client::initConnection(){
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readMessage()));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(clientConnected()));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnectedFromHost()));

    // checkConnectionTimerId - is a member of class `client`
    checkConnectionTimerId = startTimer(1000);
}


void client::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    if (event->timerId() == checkConnectionTimerId) {
        if (tcpSocket->state() != QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState) {
            tcpSocket->connectToHost(address, port, QIODevice::ReadWrite);
        }
    }
}
```